# How to create partition scheme using partition function?

Tags: sql-server, partition

I've Created `[PartitionDB]` with two file groups – `[PRIMARY]` and `[Second]` as given below.

```
 CREATE DATABASE [PartitionDB] ON
        PRIMARY
              (     NAME = N'PartitionDB',
                    FILENAME = N'D:\PartitionDB\PartitionDB.mdf' ,
                    SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB
              ),
        FILEGROUP [Second]
              (     NAME = N'PartitionDB_2',
                    FILENAME = N'D:\PartitionDB\PartitionDB_2.ndf' ,
                    SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB
              )
        LOG ON
              (     NAME = N'PartitionDB_log',
                    FILENAME = N'D:\PartitionDB\PartitionDB_log.ldf' ,
                    SIZE = 9216KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%
              )
```

It' has been created, then I created a partition function as below:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION ordersPartFunc (DATE)
AS RANGE LEFT
FOR VALUES ('2015-01-01')
```

Which was successful created and then I tried Creating a Partition Scheme:

```
    CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ordersPartScheme
    AS PARTITION ordersPartFunc
    TO ([Second], [PRIMARY])
```

But I am getting below error:

> Error: Invalid object name 'Second'.

Can anyone help me out,Please?

Comment: The file group, the partition function and the partition scheme.have to be in the same database.

Comment: Yes , it is in same database named [PartitionDB]

Comment: Did you remember to *switch* to that database after creating it and before running the subsequent commands?. So long as I separate your statements with `GO`s and insert a `USE PartitionDB` between the first two, it all runs successfully for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too. @Damien_The_Unbeliever